# Why does my package vignette freeze when sourcing data from a different package? (R)

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, knitr

I'm building a package vignette. To draw in some data for another package, I'm using:

```
file <- system.file("extdata", "sample_data.zip", package = "other_package")
```

This freezes the vignette (and sometimes my entire RStudio console) when I knit the vignette. This does not happen when I import the data from a local file path, so I am confident the cause of the crash is sourcing this data.

Additionally, I can run the code chunks without issue, but when I go to knit, then the freeze occurs.

Why might this be?

Comment: It would help if you shared access to the repo or at least provided a reproducible question. Without that, it's difficult to advise (e.g., we don't know what your vignette is doing, don't know what else the package might be doing, etc).

Comment: Currently unable to provide the repo. The package is simply producing some quick analysis/visuals off a specialized data format ("sample_data.zip"). The rest of the vignette IMO doesn't matter. I am simply reading in the data (JSON) and producing some visuals in the vignette, but it is failing when pointing at a data set from a different package. Curious if anyone else has come across this.

Comment: It will be difficult to help route out the problem without something reproducible, so you're banking on weak recommendations. Your last comment about reading json and producing visuals is very relevant, I suggest you [edit] your question and include it there (comments can easily be hidden and/or skipped by readers). Even if you cannot provide access to *that* repo, perhaps you can create a minimal package structure with just a vignette that does the bare minimum required to reproduce this hang? Be sure to include all packages involved in this vignette, it might be related. Thanks!